# How can I read an arbitrarily large file to a TCP Socket in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server

I am just learning socket programming and I am trying to write an echo client that reads from stdin and writes to a socket and then reads the server response from the socket to stdout. The problem is that I don't know how long stdin will be or how long the server's response will be. The code I am trying to use is as follows (creating the socket and connecting to the server are left out):

```
length = BUF_SIZE;
while (length == BUF_SIZE) {  // length will equal BUF_SIZE if buf is full, when length < BUF_SIZE we have reached an EOF                                 
   // Reads from STDIN to buf                                                                                                                              
   if ((length = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0){
     fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading from STDIN");
     return 4;
   }
   // Writes from buf to the socket                                                                                                                        
   if ((write(sock, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0){
     fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to socket");
     return 5;
   }
 }

if ((status = shutdown(sock, 1)) < 0){ // Shuts down socket from doing more receives                                                                      
   fprintf(stderr, "Error shutting down socket for writing");
   return 6;
}

length = BUF_SIZE; 
while (length == BUF_SIZE){
   // Read from socket to buf                                                                                                                              
   if ((length = read(sock, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0){
     fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from socket");
     return 7;
   }
   // Write from buf to STDOUT                                                                                                                             
   if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0){
     fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to STDOUT");
     return 8;
   }
}

close(sock);
exit(0);
```

BUF_SIZE is defined as 100. When I run my program the program typically connects to the server and sends the proper message, but what it writes to stdout is either nothing or gibberish.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop is only going to work the first time through.  read()/write() are only going to return the amount that they actually read/write which may well not be equal to BUF_SIZE.  Let's say you read ten bytes from the socket and then you write a hundred to stdout - the last 90 are going to be garbage.

Something along these lines will get you somewhat closer to what you want.

```
while (1)
{
    if ((length = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading from STDIN");
        return 4;
    }

    if ((write(sock, buf, length)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to socket");
        return 5;
    }

    if ((length = read(sock, buf, BUF_SIZE)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from socket");
        return 7;
    }

    if ((write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, length)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to STDOUT");
        return 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that the check should not be how much data is read from the socket, but on the socket returning -1 on a read after the remote end closed it; same for stdin.

Comment: If the socket has more than 100 bytes in it will it go through the first 100 and then go through the next 100 and the next 100 until it reaches the EOF or am I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: Yeah but that's not your problem.  It's the reverse.  There is no guarantee that 100 bytes will have gone across the network and been buffered by TCP when you do a read.  If there are less you will just get what is in the buffer and that will be returned in length.  It could be 100 or it could be 4.

Comment: Most of the code in wrong in minor ways based on this assumption.  Either you just have to read/write what you are given *or* have a known protocol (e.g. a length byte saying how many bytes are in a message or a message delimiter like a newline) and put your read/writes in a loop until it has transmitted the entire message.

Comment: Is there any way for me to measure the size of the message in the socket so that I can dynamically allocate a buffer large enough to store it?

Comment: If you go with the length byte method sure.  Read the length, allocate a buffer of that size and read into it.  But this has to be based on a scheme the client/server agree to in advance.  The socket is just a stream of bytes.  It has no structure of its own.

Comment: I posted a quick hack that is not great but should point you in the right direction.  Remember to check for when the sockets disconnect. Sorry, I have work in the morning.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your code sample. It really helped me a lot. I only needed to change from BUF_SIZE to length in my write calls and now it works.